# How to extract HTML text without any Tag using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

So, here is the HTML code I am trying to **scrape** -

```
<strong>Some Text</strong>
" Other Text I want"
<strong>Some other text</strong>
" Yet another Text I want"
```

Another Example -

```
<b>I can get:</b> This is what I also want<br />
<b>Another</b> This is another I want<br />
```

I try soup.find_all('b') and I get this output -

```
<b>I can get:</b>
<b>Another</b>
```

But I also want the next text along with this.

Comment: did you try next_sibling? `[i.next_sibling.strip() for i in soup.select('strong')]`

Comment: Yes it works, however, I'm trying to get it automatically from different areas in my HTML code(which I can't share)... But the thing is, there is text in the HTML code that I want in the sequence. So, while this helps, it doesn't fully solve my problem!

Comment: Also, it doesn't work for 

    <b>SomeHeading</b>
" The text I want"
<br>
<b>Another Heading</b>
"Another text I want
"

Comment: Perhaps looked at stripped_strings

Comment: Can you give me a proper code? I don't understand the stripped_strings!

Comment: Did you look it up?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no solution. Also, I edited the question, can you please re-check it!

Comment: for the b tag example `l = [ [j for j in i.stripped_strings] for i in soup.select('b')] ; [i for j in l for i in j]`

Comment: Just changed the example.... check it again